# Como excluir uma biblioteca externa

Tags: android, android-studio

Como faço para excluir as bibliotecas externas que geram incompatibilidade com a versão 28.

- Já exclui manualmente no diretório .idea/libraries e também cliquei sobre elas e mandei excluir em ambos os casos quando peço para o gradle sincronizar elas voltam e o erro persiste.

Estou usando as seguintes dependências

```
api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Quais as dependencias que está usando?

Comment: Editei e coloquei as dependências na pergunta, obrigado.

Comment: editei minha resposta e coloquei uma outra opção da qual eu acho a mais correta, caso funcione rs. Manda um feedback caso tenha resolvido ou não.

Comment: Eram duas imcompatibilidades: com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0 e com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0. A primeira resolveu adicionando a api com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0 nas dependencias. A Segunda não resolveu porque estou usando com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 e não tem a com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0.

Comment: Editei novamente minha resposta, remove a dependência que eu passei anteriormente e adicione a do support-v4:28.0.0 . Essa orientação é de um dos colaboradores do gms:play-services. Para mim funciona bem

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece pois algumas bibliotecas dependem da versão "X ou mais recente" das bibliotecas de suporte do Android. Uma solução documentada, pra evitar conflitos é a seguinte, coloque isso no final do build.gradle do modulo app:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            details.useVersion '26.1.0'
        }

    }
}
```

Isso irá resolver seu problema. Infelizmente algumas bibliotecas ainda não possuem uma versão mais recente, o que ocasiona esses conflitos.

**Edit1:**

O que você pode tentar ver se não tem conflito, e uma solução melhor que a de cima é adicionar a dependência com a versão menor que gera o conflito e verificar se tem a versão atualizada, no seu caso tem a versão 28.0.0

Então em dependências acrescente:

```
api 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

Você pode ver outras bibliotecas que estejam com a versão de 26.1.0 e faz o mesmo pra elas na dependência.

A dependência com.google.android.gms:.....

incluí bibliotecas com versão 26.1.0 oque faz causar o conflito.

Então resumindo, a primeira opção transforma a versão de todas dependências  'com.android.support'e altera a versão pra 26.1.0, já a segunda opção acrescenta pra biblioteca a versão mais recente da biblioteca que tava gerando o conflito.

Pode verificar que eles mesmo auxiliam a esse método:

[GitHubGooglePlayServices](https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/21)